# Are there any F/1.8 wide angle primes under 20mm for Nikon F?

Tags: lens, nikon

Nikon has a 20mm F/1.8 and there is a Sigma 14mm F/1.8 lens. I wonder if there are any fullframe Nikon F mount lenses with an aperture of F/1.8 and a focal length in between 15-19mm.

Comment: Could you explain the _photographic_ problem you're trying to solve here? This feels like something where they may be a different solution to your problem, cropping from the 14mm being the most obvious one.

Comment: Im just asking out of curiosity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are none. This is an easy [lens search](https://www.neocamera.com/search_lens.php?by=feature) to perform on Neocamera. Searching for Nikon F-mount, Prime, Full-Frame coverage, Maximum aperture of F/2 (F/1.8 falls between offered granularity), and focal-length wider than 19mm, [returns exactly one lens](https://www.neocamera.com/search_lens.php?mount=nikon&crop=1&focalwide=19%3Amax&aperturemax=2%3Amax&prime=1&by=feature) which is the Simga A 14mm F/1.8 DG HSM.

Given that 14mm is marginally wider than what you are looking for, it can probably be a good substitute since there would not be much to crop to go from 14mm to 15mm-equivalent.

*Disclosure: Neocamera is my website.*